# He is available for the interview in/on the below mentioned schedule

Tags: word-usage

I am replying to my client about the availability of a person for the interview.

Which one is correct to use. "in" or "on"?

> He is available for the interview in/on the schedule mentioned below.

Comment: "according to" is another alternative. "in" or "on" seem ok though.

Answer (score 1):

"He is available for the interview [*at these times*], on these dates: " will be less ambiguous.

"He is available for the interview between these dates". if you are not bothered about a specific date or time...

Answer (score -1):

"On" would be the appropriate preposition here I believe.

My personal rule of thumb is "on" for specific dates / days and "in" for bigger spans of time.
 The "below mentioned schedule" is a list of dates which makes it fall on the previous category.

> "on Friday", "on the 25th", "on Christmas day"
>
> "in winter", "in December", "in 2020"